# Is it possible to handle a MasterPage event in a UserControl (C#)

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls, master-pages

I've seen code to handle MasterPage events in the content Page, but if I'm loading a UserControl dynamically into the Page, can I handle the event in the UserControl instead?

Basically I have a button on the MasterPage, when it's clicked I need to make the UserControl do something, such as display text or change a value in a form.

Failing that, is it possible to make an event from one dynamically loaded UserControl fire in another on the same page?  I could then replace the button in the MasterPage with one in another UserControl

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371323/unable-to-call-an-asp-net-user-control-from-another/3371677#3371677).

The answer to that question should also apply to yours: your Page knows its master and knows its child controls.  It can wire-up a handler on the child control to an event on the master page, so the child control can perform necessary functionality when the even occurs on the master page.

Comment: Thanks - I did look before posting but must have missed that one.  Cheers!